# Restoring a differential database file "the backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing"

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to test restoring a SQL database using a full/differential approach to a different server than it was backed up from. The database is in simple recovery mode as it is a test data warehouse.

I've got a full backup which is roughly 5 days old and also a differential from today.

Now when I try to apply the differential, I get the following message:

```
RESTORE DATABASE PAS_DWH_ME
   FROM DISK='C:\MTWSQL01_Differential_Database.bak'
   WITH REPLACE

Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'PAS_DWH_ME' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I originall tried through SSMS, however it said something about breaking the LSN chain. Google suggests this is a bug with our version of SSMS.

Google suggests the way to fix this is to use the `WITH REPLACE` option, however I am using that clause.

More info:

```
restore headeronly from disk = 'C:\MTWSQL01_Full_Database.bak'
restore headeronly from disk = 'C:\MTWSQL01_Differential_Database.bak'
```

CheckpointLSN of the Full = `1063466000005158400170`

DatabaseBackupLSN of the Differential = `1063466000005158400170`

Comment: Are you sure that the differential backup matches the full backup that you've already restored? You can verify this by doing `restore headeronly from disk = '<your backup file here>'` on both the full and differential. The DatabaseBackupLSN column in the differential should match the CheckpointLSN in the full backup if they're a matched pair.

Comment: I've just checked and they are an exact match. I thought this at first, so I ran a full backup, created a table and then ran a differential. The differential was only a few megabytes big so I assumed it was attached to that Differential.

Comment: Commenting on your edit, you've got the two roles reversed. You need the CheckpointLSN from the full and the DatabaseBackupLSN from the differential. Either you're looking at the wrong columns or you mistyped it above.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is. When you restored the full backup, did you specify the 'norecovery' option? If not, recovery ran which precludes applying further restores.

Comment: Hi Ben. Yes I did specify `NO RECOVERY` (which made the db inaccessible as expected).

Comment: Then I'm at a loss. Everything you've described (restoring the full with norecovery and then trying to restore a differential from the same chain) should work.

Comment: Yeh weird hey! I just did it again- restored the full backup with norecovery and then attempted to apply the differential and same error. The backup files do have multiple databases in them and the full restore is done through SSMS whilst the differential through script, however I can't see how any of that should make a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30896/discussion-between-ben-thul-and-lock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP and I figured it out in an interactive chat session. It turns out that the backup file in question had multiple backup sets. The one that he needed to restore was not in position 1, and so didn't match the full backup that he'd restored originally. The solution was to add a `with file = n` (where n was the position of that backup set in the file).